# How can I navigate to a specific screen in React Native Notifee when user taps on a notification?

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-navigation

How can I navigate to a specific screen in React Native Notifee while in quiet and background mode?

I have implemented Firebase push notifications in my React Native app and I am utilizing the Notifee library to display notifications. Currently, I am sending data from the FCM server instead of the notification property, allowing me to successfully receive notifications through Notifee. However, I would like to enable a functionality where when a user taps on a notification, they can navigate specific screen how can I achieve this?

I have implemented a foreground event handler in my React Native app, which I call from my HomeScreen. Currently, the foreground notification navigation is working fine. Here is the code snippet for the foreground event handler:

```
export function foregroundEvent() {
    return notifee.onForegroundEvent(({ type, detail }) => {
        switch (type) {
          case EventType.DISMISSED:
            // console.log('User dismissed notification', detail.notification);
            console.log('<<<---------User dismissed notification--------->>>');
            break;
          case EventType.PRESS:
            // console.log('User pressed notification', detail.notification);
               setTimeout(() => {
            navigationServices.navigate(navigationStrings.APPROVAL)
        }, 1200)
            console.log('<<<---------User pressed notification--------->>>');
            break;
        }
      });
}
```

I have also implemented a background event handler in the index.js file of my React Native app. However, when a user presses the notification, it doesn't navigate to any particular screen. Here is the code snippet for the background event handler:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { onDisplayNotification } from './src/utils/notifeeServices';
import notifee, { EventType } from '@notifee/react-native'
import navigationServices from './src/utils/navigationServices';
import navigationStrings from './src/navigations/navigationStrings';

// fcm Register background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
  await onDisplayNotification(remoteMessage);
  
});

notifee.onBackgroundEvent(async ({ type, detail }) => {
  const { notification, pressAction } = detail;
  console.log(type );
  if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS) {
    console.log('user pressed notification background/quite mode====>');
 setTimeout(() => {
            return navigationServices.navigate(navigationStrings.ACCOUNT_FINANCE)
        }, 1200)
    await notifee.cancelNotification(notification.id);
  }
});



AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

When a notification is received from Firebase, I use the following function onDisplayNotification(data:any) to display the notification using the Notifee library:

```
export async function onDisplayNotification(data:any) {
    // Request permissions (required for iOS)

    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        await notifee.requestPermission();
    }

    // Create a channel (required for Android)
    const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
        id: data?.data?.channel_id,
        name: data?.data?.channel_name,
        sound: data?.data?.sound_name,
        // importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
    });

    // Display a notification
    await notifee.displayNotification({
        // title: data?data?.notification.title,
        // body: data?.notification.body,
        title: data?.data?.title,
        body: data?.data?.body,
        android: {
           
         
            channelId,
            smallIcon: 'ic_launcher',
            color: BlueColor,
            pressAction: {
                id: 'default',
                launchActivity: 'default'
              },
        },
    });

}
```

How can i navigate any particular screen when user press on notification?

Comment: I think navigating to screens is only possible when the app is in the background state & quit state, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: If I use Notifee for FCM background and quiet mode to display notifications, how can I redirect to a particular screen upon tapping a Notifee notification? From the server, I will send all the necessary information through the data payload, without relying on the notification object. This allows me to show Notifee notifications in both background and foreground modes.